# Dash: Print table from csv, then update table from same csv every 30 seconds

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I'm trying to read a csv file, save it to a table and print it to the browser. (that works well)
I then want to use a interval delay and callback to re-read(in the event the csv has changed) and to update the table in browser.

I run the code and it displays the table fine, but when I change the csv file, the browser table does not update. Is there something wrong in my callback.? The interval is working as the Shell creates a new line every 30 seconds, but it does not seem to re-read the csv.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, dash_table, Input, Output, callback
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta
from threading import Timer
import os.path
import os
import webbrowser

today = str(date.today())

df = pd.read_csv('I:\LABELLING\COUNT2.csv')

app = Dash(__name__)

#df = pd.read_csv(r'I:\LABELLING\COUNT2.csv')

app.layout = html.Div(id='temp_var', children=[
        html.H4(children='PRODUCTION STATS    '+today,style={'textAlign': 'left'}),
        dcc.Interval('interval-component', interval = 30000, n_intervals=0),
        dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'),id='my-table'),])

@callback(Output('my-table', 'children'),
          Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_table(df):
    df = pd.read_csv('I:\LABELLING\COUNT2.csv')
    df = df.to_json()
    return df

def open_browser():                                                                    
    if not os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN"):
        webbrowser.open_new('http://localhost:8005/')
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                            
    Timer(1, open_browser).start()
    app.run_server(host='localhost',port=8005)
```

I tried setting df to global, without success. I'm rather new to Dash, so I'm at a loss. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `df.to_dict('records')` in layout vs `df.to_json()` in `update_table()`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. That helped to get it working.

Comment: casually, a database may be a better choice for any sizeable quantity of data

Answer (score 0):

here is the code which works:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, dash_table, Input, Output, callback
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta
from threading import Timer
import os.path
import os
import webbrowser

today = str(date.today())

df = pd.read_csv(r'I:\LABELLING\COUNT2.csv')

app = Dash(__name__)

#df = pd.read_csv(r'I:\LABELLING\COUNT2.csv')

app.layout = html.Div(id='temp_var', children=[
        html.H4(children='PRODUCTION STATS    '+today,style={'textAlign': 'left'}),
        dcc.Interval('interval-component', interval = 30000, n_intervals=0),
        dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'),id='my-table'),])

@callback(Output('my-table', 'data'),
          Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_table(df):
    df = pd.read_csv(r'I:\LABELLING\COUNT2.csv')
    return df.to_dict('records')

def open_browser():                                                                    
    if not os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN"):
        webbrowser.open_new('http://localhost:8005/')
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                            
    Timer(1, open_browser).start()
    app.run_server(host='localhost',port=8005)
```